# What is the difference between Cyclic Process and Reversible Process?

Tags: thermodynamics

I want to ask the difference between Cyclic Process and Reversible Process.

Consider this graph:
[image]

If we have a process that goes from A to B then go back to A through the same path, then will it be called a Cyclic Process or Reversible Process or Both?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key concept in a reversible process is that *the system is in equilibrium with it's surroundings at every instant*. A cyclic process is different: in a cyclic process, the initial and final state are the same.

The graph that you have drawn consists of a reversible isothermal expansion(AB) and a reversible isothermal contraction(BA). Overall, the process A->B->A is a cyclic process made up of two reversible processes.

Comment: I would add that a cyclic process does not have to be reversible.  The only requirement is that the initial and final states of the system are the same.